# WSAEWOULDBLOCK error on non-blocking Connect()

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2

I am trying to connect to a server on another machine via a non-blocking connect().

However, when I do so, Connect() returns -1, and I receive WSAEWOULDBLOCK from WSAGetLastError().

MSDN Documentation states that: It is normal for WSAEWOULDBLOCK to be reported as the result from calling connect on a nonblocking SOCK_STREAM socket, since some time must elapse for the connection to be established ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

The issue is that I am always receiving the error, and -1 is returned from connect() EVEN IF my server is not running.

My socket is a SOCK_STREAM socket, just as suggested. How might I remedy this? Should I provide a timeout after the connect() call to ensure that enough time is given for connect to establish a connection?

Comment: If you try to connect to a non-existing server, it may indeed block for quite some time. There are always some network communication going on even when connecting to a non-existing server or a server port that's not open. See the [TCP 3-way handshake](http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml) to understand what happens on connection establishment.

Comment: You can use select() to block until the connect is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ConnectEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606.aspx) and pass the `OVERLAPPED` structure.  That way you can retrieve the actual status later, when the connection attempt finishes.

Comment: You can use `connect()` as well.  You can use `WSAAsyncSelect()` to detect when the connect is finished, whether it succeeded or failed, and what the error code is if failed.

Comment: @Remy: Or `WSAEventSelect` and `WSAEnumNetworkEvents`.  None of these other options are as clean and consistent as using the `OVERLAPPED` structure though.